# How to read a binary file as 16 byte HEX segments in C#?

Tags: c#, hex

I'm pretty new to C#, but I have to work with this language because it's part of a project.
What i'm doing is basically a particular file splitter/merger. 
The program will know where to split when a particular header is found, and the files have to work with 16-bit alignement, so I have to read it as "16 bytes strings" in HEX, like

```
+...p......0...
```

has to be read as

```
2B 00 00 00 70 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 30 00 00 00
```

I don't wanna read it as strings because of the encoding/charsets problem.
What can you suggest me? One problem I thought of is that reading 16 bytes per time could be pretty slow, cause I tried doing a fread buffer in C++, and it wasn't fast - at all - but I can't think any other way to do this.

Comment: You can use [Stream.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.8) method. Stream already has an internal buffer

Comment: Thank you. I tried to make it using the FileStream function, and it seems to work, but it's not "so" efficient. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I written as for now. It works, but I think it's not efficient.

```
        int byteSize = 16;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[byteSize]; // in this buffer I'm saving the 16 bytes read
            while (fs.Read(buffer, 0, byteSize) > 0)
            {
                string temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(ByteArrayToHexViaLookup32(buffer), ".{2}", "$0 ");
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
        }
```

For the hex conversion I'm using the "ByteArrayToHexViaLookup32" function, which I found on this website, and it's very fast and efficient.
The files the program it's gonna read are something like 700-800 kilobytes. 
The regex is just for console visibility/debug (adds a space every byte), so it will not be there soon.

My CPU gets a quick spike to 30% and it completes the process in 2/3 seconds, this is why I'm saying this isn't probably an efficient way to do this. (I have a 6700HQ, so I think that on a 2 Duo, the CPU on which this program is gonna run, it's gonna take muuuuch more)